# Change weight in framelayout with 2 panel

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i need to set weigth for a framelayout that contains a fragment programatically. This is possible?

I have a fragment with this xml layout inflate:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/fondodroid2"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TabOrderActivity$OrderWorkoutsFragment">    

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Then, i have a fragment instantiate in the first framelayout, and now, when i do click in a item of listview inside the first fragment, i want to set weight to 1 for have multi panel visible..
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) frameLayout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.weight = 10;
```

Comment: I think you need to set the params again to trigger an update of the ui: frameLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

Comment: At the end, do not forget to call frameLayout.requestLayout();

Answer (score 0):

In this case, You have to set frame width at 0dp for apply the layout weight and in the Linear layout, set a weight sum:

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
android:background="@drawable/fondodroid2"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".TabOrderActivity$OrderWorkoutsFragment">    

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_detail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```